# Dragging Slider place inside Draggable Control

Tags: wpf, slider, controls, draggable

I have created WPF draggable User Control. In that User Control I have placed a slider control. Now when I am dragging the slider thumb to change its values, User control is getting dragged.

I want here that if slider or scroll bar which is placed in that draggable control is clicked or pressed, the control should not drag. Please guide me on this.